# Adding Edit subnav link to Custom Buddypress Profile Tab

Tags: links, buddypress

I've created a custom tab to my buddypress user profiles called 'goals'

It displays xprofile fields, I just need to know how to make a dynamic link on the subnav that points at the 'goals' xprofile edit link tab which for example would look like

> www.dev.globalsportcoach.com/members/USERNAME/profile/edit/group/8/

The subnav is currently being generated via the following, however I've tried a few variations of the link parameter however can't get it to structure properly.

```
bp_core_new_subnav_item( array(
  'name'            => 'Edit Goals',
  'slug'            => 'edit-goals',
  'parent_url'      => 'goals',
  'parent_slug'     => 'goals',
  'screen_function' => 'false',
  'position'        => 50,
  'link'            => get_option('siteurl') . '/profile/edit/group/8/'

 ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bp_core_get_user_domain($user_id)`. This will give you the url part up to the username (with a slash at the end).

Try something like the following:

```
$user_id=bp_displayed_user_id();
$link=bp_core_get_user_domain($user_id)."profile/edit/group/8";
```

Comment: Got it working using the following 

global $current_user; 
get_currentuserinfo();  
$user_id=bp_displayed_user_id();  
$link= home_url() . '/members/' . $current_user->user_login . '/profile/edit/group/8';